# Group records by different date range

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a query against a database and group the records by different date ranges. The data type of the date field is `varchar` and in the format `dd-MMM-yyyy` e.g. `19-Aug-2016`.

The date ranges are as follow: `13–18`, `19–35`, `36–55` and `>55`. This range is determined by subtracting the current date from the date stored in the field. 
e.g. if current date is `19-Aug-2016` and date stored in the database field is `18-Aug-2003`, the year difference will be `13`. So all the date differences between `13 and 18` will be grouped together, all date differences between `19 and 35` will be grouped together etc.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried and found to not work

Comment: How do you get 13 in your example, "when current date is 19-Aug-2016 and date stored in the database field is 18-Aug-2003, the date difference will be 13" ? are you talking about the difference in YEARs? if current date is 01-Jan-2016, and date field in the database is 31-Dec-2003, is this difference = 13 or 12?
It would be good if you can give out some sample data in a table so we can figure out your precise requirements.

Comment: @jyao I have updated the question. It should be year difference.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu, your question is still vague because when we say "group by", we usually need to do an aggregation on the groups (such as max value of a column in groups, or the count of records in groups). If you only want to show ALL columns of the records in each group, it is actually an Order By not a Group By. That's why asking questions with some mock data will best serve yourself and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say storing dates in a character column is a horrible horrible idea.  Sorts won't work correctly, any form of date calculations are going to require actually casting back to a date anyway, and best of all you probably have bad data in there.

But assuming your table isn't overly large (performance on this is going to kill you because of the cast) and you don't have any bad data.  This will work

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (chardate varchar(11))
INSERT INTO #temp values ('19-Aug-2016'),('19-Mar-2010'),('10-Feb-1927'),
        ('10-Dec-2013'),('19-Mar-2000'),('10-Jan-1958')


SELECT CASE WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) < 13 THEN '<13' 
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) between 13 and 18 THEN '13-18'
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) between 19 and 35 THEN '19-35'
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) between 36 and 55 THEN '36-55'
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) > 55 THEN '>55' END AS [Range],
    COUNT(1)
FROM #temp
GROUP BY CASE WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) < 13 THEN '<13' 
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) between 13 and 18 THEN '13-18'
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) between 19 and 35 THEN '19-35'
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) between 36 and 55 THEN '36-55'
            WHEN datediff(year,CAST(chardate as date),getdate()) > 55 THEN '>55' END
```

**V2.0** You'll probably get a bit better performance with this:

```
WITH FixDate AS (SELECT CAST(chardate as date) AS realdate
                FROM #temp),
        MyRange AS (SELECT CASE WHEN datediff(year,RealDate,getdate()) < 13 THEN '<13' 
                WHEN datediff(year,RealDate,getdate()) between 13 and 18 THEN '13-18'
                WHEN datediff(year,RealDate,getdate()) between 19 and 35 THEN '19-35'
                WHEN datediff(year,RealDate,getdate()) between 36 and 55 THEN '36-55'
                WHEN datediff(year,RealDate,getdate()) > 55 THEN '>55' END AS [Range]
                FROM FixDate)
SELECT [Range], count(1)
FROM MyRange
GROUP BY [Range]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing additional information (and without flat out giving you the answer): I'd suggest to start by adding a CASE statement that will return a "DateGroup" value for each record.

This "DateGroup" value should have all of the DATEDIFF or Date Parsing Functions you're looking to run, and should return your requested "13–18, 19–35, 36–55 and >55" values.

Then you can simply GROUP BY that case statement or ORDER BY it if you wish to instead.  I think what you're actually looking for is to have the records together, which would mean an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest casting the varchar to date and then use date arithmetic. Finally use a case statement for the grouping. Something like (don't have access to sql-server):

```
select case when x between 13 and 18 then 1
            when x between 19 and 35 then 2
            when x between 36 and 55 then 3
            when x > 55 then 4
       end as grp
from ( 
    select datediff(yy, cast(d as date), getdate() ) as x
    from T
) as V;
```

Since GETDATE is non-deterministic it is probably evaluated once per row, so it might be better to determine the value outside the query and use a constant.

Comment: You have getdate() & your cast backwards :)

Comment: good observation. I'll Se if I can fix it from my phone;-)

Comment: If not comment and I can fix it for you.